# IConfiguration (replace placeholder tags before value returned)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am reading data from the files such as appsettings.json & appsettings.Production.json etc via IConfiguration (.net 6).

I want the values that are read to optional contain placeholder tags as part of that value  in the json file and when any of the methods such as

```
_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb");
_configuration.GetSection("key");
```

are used these placeholders are swapped out for other values.

Theirs 2 ways I can think this may work
If all the values from the config files are loaded into memory at startup, maybe its possible to loop though these values and replace the placeholders with actual values. Then whenever the value is read the placeholder has already been removed.

Force some custom class to be dependency injected, which inherits the original class but overrides all the methods which would call the base method, replace the tags and then return the result.

The first approach seams best as every method & extension would need overriding otherwise.
Ideally I want to change the behaviour of the value returned, not return it then replace tags as I may not have access to some of the code that reads the settings.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean you want to get the value  which  replace the placeholders with actual values before you return it?`maybe its possible to loop though these values and replace the placeholders with actual values. Then whenever the value is read the placeholder has already been removed.`What does this mean,can you share your code?

Comment: Instead of using placeholders store a proper connection string with only the things you want, then use a connection builder (eg SqlConnectionBuilder, MySqllConnectionBuilder) to set any extra values. How are you going to use the connection string? You can create a factory method that returns a proper connection string. Or you can create an overload of `AddDbContext` that configures the DbContext with the correct connection strings.